# Is it possible to store values from a slidify quiz?

Tags: javascript, r, markdown, r-markdown, slidify

Was just watching Ramnath's tutorial on Interactive Documents with R http://goo.gl/Ltiybq , which btw is absolutely brilliant! One question though is whether it would be possible to store the answer to the quiz in an R session

Comment: It is possible, but will required a javascript function to be written. I have it on my list of features to add to the quiz widget.

Comment: What would you use to write this? Node.js? Ajax?

Comment: @Ramnath Hey..Mr.Ramnath...I am wondered whether  that feature  has been. when I  was doing a search for the same, I reached this post and I found you here.. Is it done?? if yes, give me a link. pls